# Possible reason admob test ads no longer working, but real ads still are

Tags: javascript, android-studio

I have an Android app with 1mil+ downloads that uses admob. Everything works correctly, except Admob test ads (demo ad units) are not working anymore. Listing a device as test device still does the trick, and real ads work, but the sample ad unit id's seem to have stopped working. The weird thing is, I havent changed anything in my code, and the same problem occurs in previous project versions. Did admob change something over the last 5 months, explaining the

I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

errors I get?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They changed how test ads work with your package name. If you added apps-ads.txt, you can't use test ids any more with that package name. You should work with real ids and don't forget to add your current devices as a test device.

```
    public static void initTestDevicesForAds() {
        List<String> testDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        testDevices.add(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR); 
        testDevices.add("YOUR_DEVICE_ID");
        //Add new test devices here.

        RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration
                = new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                .setTestDeviceIds(testDevices)
                .build();
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
    }
```

if you still want to use test ids you can check **Caution** section real issue and solution described there. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads